# read only file system after upgrade to 15.04 with

Tags: filesystem, 15.04

The problem is occurring when loading ubuntu with systemd. If I'm manually starting with upstart (from boot menu) then everything works fine.

I've checked the disk with badsector and I have no badsectors in disk. The disk is pretty new also, so I don't think that that's a problem with disk.

I've tried to look at the output of journalctl command and I don't see anything wierd. Seems that all hardware is working properly. But then when systemd starts to launching programs if they want lock they couldn't get it because of read-only file system. Aside from that I can't say anything.

I can post like 10 photos with outputs of journalctl if it will help

That's the [output](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/mp36s1buf73w6ag/AABCXYY8R6n8_1prEs6Bnu5Ya?dl=0) of journalctl -b

Comment: So [edit] your question and tell people what the logs say.  The world is not clairvoyant, nor can people access your computer to read the logs themselves.

Comment: @JdeBP what logs do you need?

Comment: If it were my system, I'd be reading the output of `journalctl -b -x` to start with, which would lead me on to other stuff.  But don't use the `-x` option for stuff that you pass to other people for diagnosis.

Comment: @JdeBP No journal files were found. Should I do it when booting with systemd and read only file system or I can do that with upstart when everything is working fine?

Comment: Boot with systemd and view the journal since that boot.

Comment: @JdeBP I've updated my question

Comment: If it were me, I'd be looking at the systemd services that remount the root volume, to start with.  Then I'd be looking for missing orderings relative to `local-fs.target`.  But only you can do that until you show people what the logs say.

Comment: @JdeBP I've added the output of journalctl. Look at the last to photos, it's  grep root volume and local-fs.target. Don't see any errors there.

Comment: Look at this link >> http://askubuntu.com/questions/640639/ubuntu-boots-to-read-only-filesystem-after-upgrading, I have the same problem after upgrading to 16.04 and currently trying to solve with given link above.