# Ubuntu boots to "Read Only Filesystem" after Upgrading

Tags: boot, unity, grub2, graphics, 15.04

I recently upgraded to 15.04, but when my computer restarted it wouldn't boot into gui and said it was a "read only file system" I came across this

[Ubuntu boots in read-only filesystem after upgrade!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/201088/ubuntu-boots-in-read-only-filesystem-after-upgrade)

and ran this command mount

```
-o remount,rw /
```

it booted into gui, but its extremely slow and choppy how can i fix this

I read this post

http://www.randomhacks.co.uk/read-only-file-system-after-upgrade-from-ubuntu-14-10-to-ubuntu-15-04/

saying I have to edit an fstab, how do I do that?

Comment: Duplicates http://askubuntu.com/questions/640386/

Comment: Boot into BootRepair Live-CD, in terminal type `sudo fsck /dev/sda1 -y` (if sda1 is your filesystem) then, reboot, when finished, if it still not works, try again!

Answer (score 5):

Start the computer with a live-dvd/usb.

After the load open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
$ sudo -i
# fdisk -l
```

*Fdisk will inform your partitions as they are called, something like:*

```
Disk /dev/sda: 74,5 GiB, 80032038912 bytes, 156312576 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xab6eab6e

Device     Boot    Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *        2048  54750094  54748047 26,1G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       54751230 156311551 101560322 48,4G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       54751232  56702975   1951744  953M 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda6       56705024 156311551  99606528 47,5G 83 Linux
```

*For each of the Linux partitions, run the following commands:*

```
# umount /dev/sda?    
# fsck -y /dev/sda?
```

*In the example would:*

```
# umount /dev/sda1    
# umount /dev/sda6    
# fsck -y /dev/sda1
# fsck -y /dev/sda6
```

*Then continue running, assuming that `/` is `/dev/sda1`:*

```
# mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
# mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev 
# mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts
# mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
# mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
# mount --bind /etc/resolv.conf /mnt/etc/resolv.conf
# chroot /mnt
# dpkg --configure -a
# apt-get -f install
# apt-get update
# apt-get dist-upgrade
# apt-get autoremove
# apt-get clean
# umount /mnt
# exit
# reboot
```

Comment: Great! so far so good. Just stick on `apt-get -f install` but it works after I purge package that didn't met dependencies (with `dpkg --purge package`). Still cannot  `dpkg --configure  -a` due to some broken packages.